# Survival Analysis: Should my data be at transaction or customer level when looking at churn?

Tags: r, regression, survival

I am wanting to predict how long (if ever) a customer will transact with us before churning in R using survival analysis

Currently my data is at the transaction level since a customer can return after churning. **Churn is defined as not transacting for 3 months**

Here is an example of the data that I was looking to analyse:

[image]

Should I be aggregating the data at the customer level? I'm unsure about this since I was to be able to have a column for each transaction that gives the probability for that customer to churn, **3 months from the transaction date**

What would be the best approach here? Thanks a lot

Comment: As an experiment i'm using transaction level data, but at transaction, looking back for that customers to aggregate some metrics. I think this seems to be like a sensible compromise?